# When do non-trivial solutions exist, and what are they?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations, mobius-transformation

We want to find a Möbius transformation $f(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}, \; a,b,c,d \in \mathbb C$ such that

$\begin{cases}z_1 \mapsto w_1 \\ z_2 \mapsto w_2 \\ \vdots \\ z_n \mapsto w_n\end{cases}$

Assuming $z \neq \frac{-d}{c}$ we get to solve the matrix equation

$\begin{pmatrix}z_1 & 1 & -w_1 z_1 & - w_1 \\ z_2 & 1 & -w_2 z_2 & - w_2 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ z_n & 1 & -w_n z_n & - w_n \end{pmatrix} \mathbf x = \mathbf 0$ where $\mathbf x = \begin{pmatrix}a \\ b \\ c\\ d \end{pmatrix}$

For $f$ to be a function, we need to assume that $\left(z_i \mapsto w_i \right) \land \left(z_i \mapsto w_j \right)$ aren't true whenever $w_i \neq w_j$ (that is, every element in the domain is mapped to exactly one element in the range). Under this assumption, what can we say about the solutions to the matrix equation? When do they exist and what can we say about them?

Note that the trivial solution $\mathbf x = \mathbf 0$ means a Möbius transformation with our constraints cannot exist because $\mathbf x = \mathbf 0 \implies$ "$f(z) = \frac{0}0$".

Comment: Are you asking "Under what conditions does a homogeneous system of $n$ linear equations in four unknowns have a non-trivial solution?" Do you have specific criteria in mind regarding "... what can we say about the solutions to the matrix equation? When do they exist and what can we say about them?"

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Specifically, I would like to tell if there is a Möbius transformation mapping a specific subset $G \subseteq \mathbb C$ to an other specific subset $H \subseteq \mathbb C$. For example, $G, H$ could be lines, circles or even strips and whole regions of $\mathbb C$ (quadrants of $\mathbb C$ for example). Ideally I wish to construct a Möbius transformation with constraints as mentioned by carefully choosing $n$ points $z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_n$ find $a, b, c, d$ such that the function mapped them to equally careful chosen points  $w_1, w_2, \ldots, w_n$.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang The idea is, by just mapping  $z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_n$ to  $w_1, w_2, \ldots, w_n$ I would also know what a certain subset $G \subseteq \mathbb C$ will map to under $f$.

To do this, I would need to when (and what) the non-trivial solutions to the matrix equation are.

Comment: Near as I understand your set-up, you want to put your $n \times 4$ matrix into row-echelon form. If the rank is four, there is no non-trivial solution. If the rank is at most three, you're seeking solutions $(a, b, c, d)$ such that $ad - bc \neq 0$. Every such solution corresponds to a Moebius transformation carrying $z_{i}$ to $w_{i}$ for each $i$.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I agree, but that's really not what I'm asking for. What does it *mean* for the points and their relationships that the rank is as most three? Talking about linear independent vectors doesn't give a clear  picture of how it relates to the Möbius transformation. I also don't know if this is a good approach to the original problem, which was to map a specific subset $G \in \mathbb C$ to an other specific subset  $G \in \mathbb C$. Say that I want to send $|z-1|<2$ to the upper half plane. Can I use this method, and map a few points in $|z-1|<2$ to the desired region?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Will that ensure that the whole region maps to where I want it? Can I use this "point-mapping"-approach to map subsets to each other? Or is there any smarter way of doing it?

Comment: If you're interested in mapping _regions_, looking at several points is probably not a good strategy: The Moebius group is three-point transitive (any ordered triple is uniquely the image of any fixed ordered triple), but to map regions you're looking at infinitely many points. How much do you know about the structure of the Moebius group (e.g., it maps circles/disks to circles/disks in the sphere)?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I know generalized circles maps to generalized circles, so mapping three discrete points is enough if you want to do a such mapping. So I was looking for a way to relate mappings between subsets via the matrix equation to extend the method.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what you mean by "extend the method". For most regions $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$ (homeomorphic to disks, say), there is no Moebius bijection from $G_{1}$ to $G_{2}$; for most pairs of sets of four or more points, there is no Moebius transformation carrying one set to the other, etc., etc.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang So, I can't map $n$ points in $G$ to some points in $H$ and hope for the best; that is, hope that whole of $G$ will be mapped to $H$?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's right: For example, if $G_{1} = G_{2}$ is the unit disk and we map $0 \to 0$, $1/3 \to 2/3$, and $-1/3 \to -2/3$ (all points of the disk), the unique Moebius extension maps $G_{1}$ outside $G_{2}$.

Comment: By the way, the (famous?) movie [Moebius transformations revealed](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~arnold/moebius/) is highly worthwhile if you haven't seen it.